# Where are the dumpfiles that savevm command produce in qemu?

Tags: migration, qemu, kvm

I'd want to do some migration work with `qemu`, but met some difficulty. So if I get the dumpfiles that `savevm` command produce, it might be helpful. Does anyone know where `qemu` save these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To issue the *savevm* command the file-format of your configured disk must support snapshots, e.g. the command doesn't work if you use the *raw* file-format, a raw block-device or no disk-device at all.

To answer your question: it is stored as a snapshot inside of your diskimage-file. To view your snapshots issue:

```
qemu-img snapshot -l mydiskimage.qcow2
```